# Aribitrary System.DateTime to four character military time string

Tags: c#, string, datetime, time

How would I convert an arbitrary System.DateTime to a four character military time string.

- Example 1: 7am would be "0700"
- Example 2: 2pm would be "1400"

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")
```

do what you need?